# Programatically add a page to a known parent

Tags: wagtail

I would like to create programatically a sub page for a known parent. How can I do that? The page creation will takes place in a signal receiver: the page is created on publication of another page.

Answer (score 19):

Add a revision as well.

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
from models import MyPage

home = Page.objects.get(id=3) # or better Page query
my_page = MyPage(title="test", body="<h1>the body</h1>")
home.add_child(instance=my_page)

# later when a cms user updates the page manually 
# there will be no first revision to compare against unless
# you add a page revision also programmatically.

my_page.save_revision().publish()
```

You can see how wagtail does this in the wagtailadmin pages create view (line 156).
https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/stable/1.13.x/wagtail/wagtailadmin/views/pages.py

Update 2018-09-18:
I built a 700 page site including 200 generated pages. I never added an initial Revision anywhere and no editors complained. After the first manual edit there will be a Revision. Go ahead and add an initial Revision if you think it is needed for traceability.

Comment: For another example: https://gist.github.com/veuncent/9dab311125401c1886eb7c6998f5f387

Answer (score 16):

To create a page programmatically:

```
page = SomePageType(title="My new page", body="<p>Hello world</p>")  # adjust fields to match your page type
parent_page.add_child(instance=page)
```

Answer (score 3):

Below is my complete code to create a multi language page structure programatically. It will replace the "Wagtail Welcome Page" with a *LanguageRedirectionPage* instance.

More information about multi language pages:
[Wagtail Docs - Internationalization](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.0.1/advanced_topics/i18n/duplicate_tree.html#creating-a-multilingual-site-by-duplicating-the-page-tree)

The page structure is as follows:

- Page

  - LanguageRedirectionPage (will redirect to /en)

    - Page (en)
    - Page (de)
    - Page (fr)

where the created *Site* instance at the end of the code points to the *LanguageRedirectionPage* instance. This is the entry point of our application.

```
# Deletes existing pages and sites
Site.objects.all().delete()
Page.objects.filter(pk=2).delete() # Deletes Wagtail welcome page
root_page = Page.objects.filter(pk=1).get()

# Adds a LanguageRedirectionPage as a child of the Root Page
app_name = '[Your Project Name]'
page_slug = app_name.lower().replace(" ", "")
sub_root_page = LanguageRedirectionPage(
    title=app_name,
    draft_title=app_name,
    slug=page_slug,
    live=True,
    owner=account,
)

root_page.add_child(instance=sub_root_page)
sub_root_page.save_revision().publish()

# Adds some language pages
for code,caption in dict(settings.LANGUAGES).items():
    print(code, caption)
    sub_root_page.add_child(instance=Page(
        title=caption,
        slug=code,
        live=True,
        owner=account,
    ))

# Adds a new Site instance (See Settings -> Sites in your Wagtail admin panel)
Site.objects.create(
    hostname='localhost',
    port='80',
    site_name=app_name,
    root_page=sub_root_page,
    is_default_site=True,
)
```

Comment: All is good but you have to use site = Site(...); site.save() for pages consistency to avoid warning of no pages available.

Answer (score 0):

I left you what worked for me, using a django migration:

```
from django.db import migrations
from wagtail.models import Page, Locale, Site


def create_wagtail_home_page(apps, schema_editor):
    HomePage = apps.get_model("blog.HomePage")
    ContentType = apps.get_model("contenttypes.ContentType")

    # Get the content type for the Page model
    page_content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label="wagtailcore", model="page")

    root_page = Page.objects.order_by("id").first()

    default_locale = Locale.objects.first()

    home_page = HomePage(title="Home", body="", locale_id=default_locale.id, content_type=page_content_type)

    root_page.add_child(instance=home_page)

    # Refresh the home page instance, this Must be a PageInstance for the next step to work
    home_page = Page.objects.order_by("-id").first()

    # Create a site with the new homepage set as the root
    Site.objects.create(hostname="localhost", root_page=home_page, is_default_site=True)



def reverse_home_page(apps, schema_editor):
    HomePage = apps.get_model("blog.HomePage")
    HomePage.objects.all().delete()
    


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ("blog", "0002_homepage"),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_wagtail_home_page, reverse_home_page),
    ]
```