# Is there any way to create and publish pages by executing python script in wagtail?

Tags: python, content-management-system, wagtail

I can create and publish pages(which I have created by inheriting Page class) by using wagtail admin interface by using the process below.

```
class HomePage(Page):
   template = 'tmp/home.html'

   def get_context(self, request):
       context = super(HomePage, self).get_context(request)
      context['child'] = PatientPage.objects.child_of(self).live()
      return context

class PatientPage(Page):
    template = 'tmp/patient_page.html'
    parent_page_types = ['home.HomePage',]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    birth_year = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('name'),
        FieldPanel('birth_year'),
   ]
```

Now, I want to automate creating and publishing of many pages of PatientPage class and append those to Homepage as child by running a python script.

Comment: please put whatever you tried yet

Comment: Please provide us with code samples of what you tried until now. That way we can help you more effectively.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/43040023/8070948

Comment: descriptions has been updated.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried that and it worked for me. 

@LBBenJohnston

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is already answered well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040023/programatically-add-a-page-to-a-known-parent). However, here is a more specific answer to your situation with instructions on how to make this a script that can be run.

To run this custom command script whenever you need, you can create this as a [custom django-admin command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/#module-django.core.management).

Example: my_app/management/commands/add_pages.py

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
from .models import HomePage, PatientPage  # assuming your models are in the same app


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Creates many pages'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        # 1 - get your home page
        home_page = Page.objects.type(HomePage).first()  # this will get the first HomePage
        # home_page = Page.objects.get(pk=123) # where 123 is the id of your home page

        # just an example - looping through a list of 'titles'
        # you could also pass args into your manage.py command and use them here, see the django doc link above.
        for page_title in ['a', 'b', 'c']:
            # 2 - create a page instance, this is not yet stored in the DB
            page = PatientPage(
                title=page_title,
                slug='new-page-slug-%s'page_title,  # pages must be created with a slug, will not auto-create
                name='Joe Jenkins',  # can leave blank as not required
                birth_year=1955,
            )

            # 3 - create the new page as a child of the parent (home), this puts a new page in the DB
            new_page = home_page.add_child(instance=page)

            # 4a - create a revision of the page, assuming you want it published now

            new_page.save_revision().publish()

            # 4b - create a revision of the page, without publishing

            new_page.save_revision()
```

You can run this command using `$ python manage.py add_pages`

Note: On Python 2, be sure to include `__init__.py` files in both the management and management/commands directories as done above or your command will not be detected.