# Create pages programaticallhy with Django and Wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

I managed to programatically create pages using Django Management Commands as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040023/programatically-add-a-page-to-a-known-parent) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47749708/is-there-any-way-to-create-and-publish-pages-by-executing-python-script-in-wagta).

How do I link those pages to other models like tags, categories and authors?

Here is the model of the page I want to create:

```
class BlogPage(Page):

    ## Fields I can create programatically
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    ## Fields I dont know what to do with
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through='BlogPageTag', blank=True)
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField('blog.BlogCategory', blank=True)
    authors = ParentalManyToManyField('blog.BlogAuthor', blank=True)

    def main_image(self):
        gallery_item = self.gallery_images.first()
        if gallery_item:
            return gallery_item.image
        else:
            return None
```

Here is the code that I use to create the page without tags, authors and categories:

```
    from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
    from wagtail.models import Page
    from blog.models import BlogIndexPage, BlogPage

    class Command(BaseCommand):
        help = 'Create new Blog Page'

        def handle(self, *args, **options):

        home_page = Page.objects.type(BlogIndexPage).first()  

        new_page = BlogPage(
            title="My Page",
            slug="mypage",
            date = "2022-07-17",
            intro = "Some Intro",
            body = "Some Body",           
        )

        home_page.add_child(instance=new_page)

        new_page.save_revision().publish()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have used ParentalManyToManyFields, you can add categories and authors to the new_page before saving it for the first time.

```
    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        home_page = Page.objects.type(BlogIndexPage).first()  

        new_page = BlogPage(
            title="My Page",
            slug="mypage",
            date = "2022-07-17",
            intro = "Some Intro",
            body = "Some Body",           
        )
        category, created = BlogCategory.objects.get_or_create(name="Category 1")
        new_page.categories = [category]

        home_page.add_child(instance=new_page)

        new_page.save_revision().publish()
```

I don't have a tagging example handy. Because it goes through TaggableManager, you may have to use `add` or `set` from https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Comment: I tried using `set` with the tag name, but it created new tags for every letter that I input to it. I then tried to use filters to input the full tags to `set` or `add`, but it did not work either. Using `add` with the tag name did the trick. I posted the full code, including authors, tags and categories below.

Comment: That add works. If you want to add multiple tags at the same time, this should work: `new_page.tags.set(['MYTAG', 'YOURTAG'])`. Even if you only have one tag, you need to pass a list to `.set()`

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working based on the answer from cnk:

```
    from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
    from wagtail.models import Page
    from blog.models import BlogIndexPage, BlogPage
    
    class Command(BaseCommand):
        help = 'Create new Blog Page'
        
        def handle(self, *args, **options):
        
        home_page = Page.objects.type(BlogIndexPage).first()  
        
        new_page = BlogPage(
            title="My Page",
            slug="mypage",
            date = "2022-07-17",
            intro = "Some Intro",
            body = "Some Body",           
        )
        
        category, created = BlogCategory.objects.get_or_create(name="MYCATEGORY")
        new_page.categories = [category]
        
        author, created = BlogAuthor.objects.get_or_create(name="MYAUTHOR")
        new_page.authors = [author]
        
        new_page.tags.add('MYTAG')
        
        home_page.add_child(instance=new_page)
        new_page.save_revision().publish()
```