# Creating new wagtail home_page

Tags: wagtail

I changed a bit wagtail 0001_initial.py and 0002_chreate_homepage.py and if i do migrate/makemigrations i get Server Error

[image]

Here is how i changed these files

0001_initial.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.11.9 on 2018-02-11 16:32
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import django.db.models.deletion


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
        ('wagtailcore', '0040_page_draft_title'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='HomePage',
            fields=[
                ('page_ptr', models.OneToOneField(auto_created=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, parent_link=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, to='wagtailcore.Page')),
                ('tournament_section_title', models.CharField(blank=True, help_text='Title to display above the next matches', max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('matches_section_title', models.CharField(blank=True, help_text='Title to display above the next matches', max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('news_section_title', models.CharField(blank=True, help_text='Title to display above the News section on Home page', max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('presentation_screen_section_title', models.CharField(blank=True, help_text='Title to display above the News section on Home page', max_length=255, null=True)),
                ('matches_section', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, help_text='Choose a page to link to for the Matches Page', null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='+', to='wagtailcore.Page', verbose_name='Choose ')),
                ('news_section', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, help_text='Choose a page to link to for the News Page.', null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='+', to='wagtailcore.Page', verbose_name='News')),
                ('presentation_screen_section', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, help_text='Choose a page to link to for the Presentation Screen Page.', null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='+', to='wagtailcore.Page', verbose_name='Presentation Screen')),
                ('tournament_section', models.ForeignKey(blank=True, help_text='Choose a page to link to for the Matches Page', null=True, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.SET_NULL, related_name='+', to='wagtailcore.Page', verbose_name='Choose ')),
            ],
            options={
                'abstract': False,
            },
            bases=('wagtailcore.page',),
        ),
    ]
```

and 0002_chreate_homepage.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations


def create_homepage(apps, schema_editor):
    # Get models
    ContentType = apps.get_model('contenttypes.ContentType')
    Page = apps.get_model('wagtailcore.Page')
    Site = apps.get_model('wagtailcore.Site')
    HomePage = apps.get_model('base.HomePage')

    # Delete the default homepage
    # If migration is run multiple times, it may have already been deleted
    Page.objects.filter(id=2).delete()

    # Create content type for homepage model
    homepage_content_type, __ = ContentType.objects.get_or_create(
        model='homepage', app_label='home')

    # Create a new homepage
    homepage = HomePage.objects.create(
        title="Home",
        draft_title="Home",
        slug='home',
        content_type=homepage_content_type,
        path='00010001',
        depth=2,
        numchild=0,
        url_path='/home/',
    )

    # Create a site with the new homepage set as the root
    Site.objects.create(
        hostname='localhost', root_page=homepage, is_default_site=True)


def remove_homepage(apps, schema_editor):
    # Get models
    ContentType = apps.get_model('contenttypes.ContentType')
    HomePage = apps.get_model('base.HomePage')

    # Delete the default homepage
    # Page and Site objects CASCADE
    HomePage.objects.filter(slug='home', depth=2).delete()

    # Delete content type for homepage model
    ContentType.objects.filter(model='homepage', app_label='home').delete()


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('base', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_homepage, remove_homepage),
    ]
```

Which way I have to do this, so if I deploy my project to heroku and run migrate it will automatically create HomePage that i changed.

my Project tree

```
-Project/
 |-requirements
 |-treichle-cup
   |-base
   |-search
   |-settings
   |-static
   |-templates
```

In site settings my HomePage is exist and set as Root Page

[image]

Comment: Here is a similar question about how to create a page programmatically - it does not do it in a migration but it might help. https://stackoverflow.com/q/43040023/8070948