# How to insert a new page data manually in wagtail database table?

Tags: wagtail

I am using wagtail 2.10.2. And I want to use SQL query to manually create a page entry for a page type in database. Would like to know the steps and possible complications in doing so. Thanks

How to achieve this with out breaking the existing setup which is up and running.

Comment: I would definitely not recommend doing this directly in SQL - there are LOTS of details to keep track of, such as how the tree structure is represented, and the whole point of an ORM like Django is to hide those workings from you. For creating a page record in Python code, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040023/programatically-add-a-page-to-a-known-parent

Comment: @gasman hey it make sense, but for my use-case what I have is just write access to the DB and some translated localised content of already existing pages in a csv and I need to bulk insert these translated pages in wagtail.

Comment: What's stopping you from doing that in Python code? A management command (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/howto/custom-management-commands/) would be a perfect fit for this.